# Extracting Adobe PDF Form Properties

Tags: pdf, adobe

I have searched for an answer to this question but perhaps I am searching with the incorrect terminology as I have found nothing so far. Any help would be great!

I would like to extract the positions of text fields, check boxes, radio buttons, list boxes, etc. from an Adobe PDF file. Is there a way to do this? Is there a way to do this with Python?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: There are lots of libraries to parse PDF file data such as this. However this sort of question is best asked on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

Does this post help? It runs through extracting text from a pdf and has a line of code commented out which will show the coordinates of text. [Finding and extracting specific text from URL PDF files, without downloading or writing (solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68676118/finding-and-extracting-specific-text-from-url-pdf-files-without-downloading-or)